# PHP: Get string from within Array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using facebook SDK and I'm trying to get a string from an array which is the facebook php sdk response.

Basically, I get the age_range from facebook and I need to get the value of age_range.

The age range always is an array for some strange reason.

It looks like this:

```
[age_range] => Array
    (
        [min] => 21
    )
```

so, in my php I have this:

```
$age_range = $me['age_range'];
```

but when i insert this `$age_range` into mysql database, I get the word `Array` inserted into mysql database!

But all i need is the `21` or any other number that returns back from age range.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `$age_range = $me['age_range']['min'];` work?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. When you get a minute if you could click the tick to the left of my answer that would be great :)

Comment: @MattKent, Will do bud... its saying i need to wait 3 minutes before accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, simply change:

```
$age_range = $me['age_range'];
```

to

```
$age_range = $me['age_range']['min'];
```